# Correct syntax for RestClient::Resource PUT when using ssl_ca_file

Tags: ruby, jira, rest-client

Pulling out my hair trying to get a REST update to JIRA ticket working, specifically while specifying a certificate file to be used in the transaction.

I'm using the RestClient gem (2.0.0) in Ruby 2.2.0.

Per the documentation ([here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client), and [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rest-client/rest-client/RestClient/Resource#put-instance_method)) I need to create a new Resource and then call a method on it, rather than the shorter more immediate syntax.

POST requests to JIRA work fine using this construction style:

```
endpoint = "#{opts['jiraHost']}/rest/api/2/issue"
request = RestClient::Resource.new(endpoint,
   ssl_ca_file: certfile, 
   headers: {
     Authorization: 'Basic b3B....', 
     content_type: :json, 
     accept: :json}
)
response = request.post(ticketParams.to_json)
```

I get a success response and a ticket is created.

A lightly modified version that uses the PUT verb fails with a 400 Bad Request.

```
endpoint = "#{opts['jiraHost']}/rest/api/2/issue/#{ticket[:issueKey]}"
request = RestClient::Resource.new(endpoint, 
     ssl_ca_file: certfile, 
     headers: {
       Authorization: 'Basic b3B....', 
       content_type: :json, 
       accept: :json}
)
response = request.put(ticketParams.to_json)
```

**The infurating part is that when doing this to a non-SSL JIRA installation and omitting the SSL CA File argument, the update works just fine. I can make same update call through Postman and it works fine.**

In the samples given in the documentation, there were examples of specifying a certificate file with a GET, but not other verbs, and only one example of Resource.post(payload). I suspect I'm putting the ssl_ca_file in the wrong place, but I've tried all variations I can think of to no avail.

(Someone will ask why I can't rely on the system's certificate store. I can't; I've tried everything, and only specifying the cert file allows me to connect.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the [#execute](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#passing-advanced-options) method directly?

Comment: Tried it, tucking the params into the headers option hash as shown in the docs, with the same 400 error:
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :put, url: endpoint,
                            ssl_ca_file: certfile,
                            headers: options)
where the options hash looks like
{:authorization=>"Basic b3B...",
 :content_type=>:json,
 :params=>
  {"fields"=>
    {"customfield_15110"=>"0.33%",
     "customfield_15122"=>"0.41%"
  }
}

Comment: I've never used the RestClient gem, but that surely seems like a bug. Have you tried enabling the logger to take a peek at the request. `RestClient.log = 'stdout'`

Answer (score 0):

My bad... the answer lay in the error.response.body, which contained a JIRA specific error message. Wasn't the SSL option at all.